# Count of specific values in a python dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I have referred multiple answers here but did not find what I was looking for, basically I have converted a data frame to dictionary.

```
Dict_of_risk = {'Jan' : 'HIGH','HIGH','HIGH','LOW','LOW','LOW', 'FEB':'LOW', 'LOW', 'HIGH','HIGH','HIGH','HIGH'}
```

I am looking for a way to get the below:

Jan
HIGH : 3
LOW : 3

FEB
HIGH: 4
LOW: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Counter`

You can call HIGH as using `sub_dict['Jan']['HIGH']` or `sub_dict['Feb']['HIGH']`

```py
from collections import Counter

Dict_of_risk = {'Jan': ('HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'LOW', 'LOW'),
                'FEB': ('LOW', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'HIGH')}

sub_dict = {}
for_dict = {}

for key, value in Dict_of_risk.items():
    for_dict = {}
    for sub_key, sub_value in Counter(Dict_of_risk[key]).items():
        for_dict[sub_key] = sub_value
    sub_dict[key] = for_dict

print(sub_dict)
print("['Jan']['HIGH'] = {}".format(sub_dict['Jan']['HIGH']))
```

Output:

```py
{'Jan': {'HIGH': 3, 'LOW': 3}, 'FEB': {'LOW': 2, 'HIGH': 4}}
sub_dict['Jan']['HIGH'] = 3
```

Comment: It's perfect but is there a way to call HIGH. Basically I want to assign that 3 in a table.

Comment: You can call HIGH using `sub_dict['Jan']['HIGH']` or `sub_dict['Feb']['HIGH']`. Please see my updated answer